# quickly find the indexes of common rows in two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

Thanks in advance for the help.

Suppose that I have two matrices: A and B.  I want to know which rows in A are also in B.  For example given

```
A = [1 2; 3 4] and B = [1 2; 5 6; 7 8]
```

I would like an output of

```
out = [1 0];
```

A simple way of doing this is to use for loops but my A and B matrices are both very large.  Using for loops is thus exceedingly slow (it would likely take several hours to handle just two matrices and I have several thousand to compare).  Is there a way that I could do this using Matlab's built-in functions (which are optimized to handle matrix operations)?

Comment: What are A and B's typical sizes? Do both of them always have two columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to do it with MATLAB's built-in functions!

```
out = ismember(A, B, 'rows');
```

Comment: This solution is much better, +1